# find -exec in bash script with variable expansion

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, posix

I'm trying to run a command similar to the one below in a bash script. It should search through all subfolders of `$sourcedir` and copy all files of a certain type to the root level of `$targetdir`.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# These are set as arguments to the script, not hard-coded
sourcedir="/path/to/sourcedir"
targetdir="/path/to/targetdir"

find "$sourcedir" -type f -name "*.type" -exec sh -c 'cp "$1" "$2/`basename "$1"`"' "{}" "$targetdir" \;
```

This seems to be pretty close, except that `{}` isn't being passed in as `$2` to `-exec sh -c ...`

I would like to do this as close to the "right way" as possible, with tolerance for special characters in filenames (specifically single quote characters).

**Edit:** I see people suggesting using `xargs` or argument chaining. I was under the impression that this is only ok for a limited number of arguments. If I have, for example, thousands of .jpg files I'm trying to copy from a number of gallery directories into a giant slideshow directory, will the solutions chaining arguments still work?

**Edit 2:** My problem was I was missing a `_` before my first option to sh in the `-exec` command. For anyone who is curious about how to make the find command work, add the `_` and everything will be fine:

```
find "$sourcedir" -type f -name "*.type" -exec sh -c 'cp "$1" "$2"' _ "{}" "$targetdir" \;
```

I have accepted an answer below though because it accomplishes the same task, but is more efficient and elegant.

Comment: That is exactly why `xargs` was ever created, to automatically handle huge amounts of arguments on regular commands that had limits.  Also to consider, most of the max argument limits, have been vastly improved for the standard GNU utils.  You also will see a performance benefit, avoiding all those process forks, which on thousands of files is relevant.

Comment: With gnu-find and + instead of ";", you can handle multiple arguments at once with find too. And you save the complicated argument passing with -print0.

Comment: @userunknown: I'm responding to this below your answer.

Comment: @user unknown Well, I do LOVE this code. It's at least fully __POSIX-compliant__ and will work without any GNU stuff on the machine at all. There are those times when you *do* need this, especially on servers at work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to copy files of a specific type, to a specific directory?  This is best done with `xargs`, and you don't even need that `sh`.  This is a more appropriate way to do it, should also run more efficiently.

```
find "$sourcedir" -type f -name "*.type" | xargs cp -t targetdir
```

If you need to handle special file names, then use `NULL` as your seperator

```
find "$sourcedir" -type f -name "*.type" -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t "$targetdir"
```

Comment: For the 2nd case, don't forget to add `-print0` to `find` and `-0` to `xargs`

Comment: @ SiegeX, already was doing that, before i noticed your comment.

Comment: Also, `NULL` is not necessary if you use `'{}'`, its important when you don't.  The real benefit between one of the other, other than `POSIX` compliance, is performance.

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass `{}` as an argument to the shell then loop over each arg.

```
find "$sourcedir" -type f -name "*.type" -exec sh -c 'for f; do cp "$f" "$0"; done' "$targetdir" {} +
```

*Note*: The way this works is that the first arg to a shell is the *name of the shell*, we can exploit this by passing the name as the `$targetdir` and then use the special parameter `$0` inside the shell script to access that targetdir.

Comment: `"$targetdir"` is not expanded inside single quotes.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't believe in the church of xargs:

```
find "$sourcedir" -type f -name "*.mp3" -exec cp -t "$targetdir" {} +
```

Explanation:

```
cp -t a b c d
```

copies b, c and d to the target dir a.

```
-exec cmd {} +
```

invokes the command on a big bunch of files at once, not one after the other (which is standard, if you use `";"` instead of `+`) . This is why we have to pull the targetdir to the front and mark it explicitly as target.

This works for gnu-find and might not for other implementations of find. Of course it relies on the -t -flag too.

TechZilla is of course in so far right, as `sh` isn't needed to invoke cp.

If you don't use `xargs`, which is most of the time needless in combination with `find`, you're saved from learning the `-print0` and `-0` flag.

Comment: Obvisouly, which method anyone might prefer is somwhat subjective.  With that said, there does exist reasons to still use `xargs`.  Biggest example, what if you are not finding files?  I use xargs in place of general `for` loops all the time, `find` is much smaller in scope.  In addition, `find` only supports that `+` if you are using GNU `find`, it's not defined in POSIX.  So while you should feel free to prefer `find` alone, It does not do everything xargs does.  When you consider GNU `xargs` you also get `-P` which does multi-core.  Its worth learning `xargs` regardless.

Comment: Subjectivity speaking, my opinion obviously does differ.  Objectively on the other hand, your answer is also correct.  It is one of the few best solutions available.

Comment: @TechZilla: I hope to remember to revisit this site, when find starts supporting parallel invocation. :) In most cases with copying/moving, disk speed will be the limiting factor, but SSDs might change the picture. You're right, that a non-GNU-solution to provide is a fine thing. Else, the find-solution is objectively shorter, simpler, and uses only two processes.

Answer (score 0):

```
read -p "SOURCE: " sourcedir
read -p "TYPE: " type
read -p "TARGET: " targetdir
find -L $sourcedir -iname "*.$type" -exec cp -v {} $targetdir \;
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation of your solution.