# find with -exec eval of $0

Tags: find, parameter, exec

In the following command I would like to know why `$0` was evaluated to the file found by `find` and not the `echo` command.

```
$ find . -type f -perm -u=x -exec bash -c '
  /bin/echo $0 is the name of the file' {} \;
```

I know that if I had used double quotes, `$0` would equal `-bash` and using single quotes delays the expansion, but why doesn't it expand to `/bin/echo` since that is the called command (which normally would be `$0`)?

Comment: I'd understand why you'd want `$0` to expand to `bash`, but not `echo`.  Do you expect `rm "$0"` to attempt to remove `rm`? See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/140779 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152391

Comment: I don't want that behavior, I find this more useful, but I expected the behavior typically found when using $0 in a shell script where $0 represents the script itself.  I was curious how it was working, not wishing it worked differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `bash` manual page:

```
 -c    If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first 
       non-option argument command_string.  If there are arguments after 
       the command_string,  they are assigned to the positional 
       parameters, starting with $0.
```

The filename is given to `bash` as an argument using the braces `{}`, so it is assigned to `$0`. The expansion of `$0` is then done by bash *prior* to calling `/bin/echo`.

Comment: As discussed [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93331/80216) and [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30677/80216), some people like to insert a placeholder word between `sh -c "(command)"` and the argument list, if any, to straighten out this confusion.  For example, your command would become `find . -type f … -exec bash -c '/bin/echo $1 is the name of the file' placeholder {} \;`.  In the shell command, `$0` would equal `placeholder`.  (It is common to use things like `sh` or `_` as the placeholder.)