# Refactoring for loop over find to use exec

Tags: shell-script, find

I have a bash script which does similar to the following:

```
for src in $(find -H "$DOTFILES_ROOT" -maxdepth 2 -name '*.sym' -not -path '*.git*')
 do
   dst="$HOME/$(basename "${src%.*}")"
   link_file "$src" "$dst"
 done
```

I've ran shellcheck on my script and it returned

```
For loops over find output are fragile. Use find -exec or a while read loop.
```

Which I've read an understood, and it makes sense to me e.g.

```
find -H "$(pwd)" -maxdepth 2 -name '*.sym' -not -path '*.git*' -exec echo {} \;
```

But I'm not sure how to make it work with a variable as I have in the for loop

Comment: Maybe in your case the `while read` loop is the better choice.

Comment: You could do worse than use [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30679/21233) as a starting point

Comment: Read the top voted answers on [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Comment: can you link to shellcheck, some will find it interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The variables in the `for` loop that you have are `src` and `dst`.  `src` is the pathname of a file given to the loop by `find` and `dst` is computed from `src`.

Your loop can be converted to a `find -exec` command like this:

```
find -H "$DOTFILES_ROOT" -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '.git' -prune -o \
    -type f -name '*.sym' -exec sh -c '
        link_file "$1" "$HOME/$( basename "${1%.*}" )"' sh {} ';'
```

I have assumed that you by `-not -path '*.git*'` intend to not look in `.git` directories.  This is the same as `-type d -name '.git' -prune` in the command above, but with `-prune` we stop `find` from even entering those directories.

Once we have weeded out the `.git` directories, we look for `.sym` files.  When one is found, the command from your loop is executed.  The command is executed through `sh -c` (to be able to do fancy things with parameter substitutions and `basename`) and the pathname of the found file is made available inside as `$1`.

One could even incorporate your loop (almost) as you have written it:

```
find -H "$DOTFILES_ROOT" -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '.git' -prune -o \
    -type f -name '*.sym' -exec sh -c '
        for src do
            dst="$HOME/$( basename "${src%.*}" )"
            link_file "$src" "$dst"
        done' sh {} +
```

In this case, the `sh -c` script is given not a single pathname but a number of them (due to the `+` at the end of the `-exec`), so we loop over these and perform the action.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)